# Search for contacts with documents

Tags: search, attachments, document-management

I am in a process of migrating CiviCRM data to a separate database. I am using the **Documenten** extension to store some files attached to my contacts and I would like to find the contacts which have documents attached.

The extension page says it should enable this functionality but I cannot find it. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be at url /civicrm/documents/search.

It looks like you need administer CiviCRM permission to use it.

If for some reason it isn't finding it try rebuilding the menu with /civicrm/menu/rebuild?reset=1

I'm assuming you mean this extension:
https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.documents/blob/master/documents.php#L95

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. The URL appears to work, though I still can't find it in the menu. Moreover, I get the following error when I try to rebuild the menu: "API (CiviRuleAction, get) does not exist (join the API team and implement it!)".

Still I guess I can add the URL manually so this is not a problem

Comment: Maybe you used to have CiviRules enabled and have some left over entries related to it? Or something like that?